# How to use map function to Mobx observable state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, mobx

Now I would like to use Map function to show a component with each array.

But, my code with map is not working rightly.
In firestore, there are 3 document in "food" collection but this map function can only render one document.

This is my code below in render component.

```
renderItemBox() {
    const { store } = this.props;
    const items = store.restaurantStore.Items;
    return items.map((value, index) => {
      console.log(items);
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity key={index}>
          <View style={styles.itemsBox}>
            <View style={styles.itemsImageBox}>
              <Image
                source={require('../../assets/Images/Home/HomeListImageShop.jpg')}
                style={styles.itemsImage}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text style={styles.itemsName}>
                {value[index].name}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.itemsTag}>
                {value[index].tag}
              </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text style={styles.itemsDescription}>
                {value[index].shortDescription}
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.likeButtonBox}
                onPress={this.handleLikeButton.bind(this)}
              >
                {this.handleLikeImage()}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });
  }
```

In addition to this, I set store component in my project.
This code above is importing observable state(array) from that store.

Below one is that store.

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';
import firebase from 'firebase';

class RestaurantStore {
 @observable Items = [];

 @action handleFirestoreCollectionOfFoods () {
   const db = firebase.firestore();
   db.collection('foods')
     .get()
     .then((snapshot) => {
       const preItems = [];
       snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         const docData = doc.data();
         preItems.push(docData);
       });
       this.Items.push(preItems);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
     });
 }
}

export default RestaurantStore;
```

Fortunetely, this store can import complete document from firestore.
I did check that with console.log.

So, does someone know how to use map function to mobx state completely?

Comment: It's not related to map function. do you mark the component as observer ?!

Comment: Sure, and in the component with map function, I can get the observerbaleArray from mobx store. But I cannot render all of array with map

Comment: Try to mock items array and check the output. I think render logic should be revised. Map and observable arrays work very well together.

Comment: I did that before. In that time, all of the objects in an array can be rendered by map function. I have just replaced that object array and function to import data from firestore to store component.

Comment: Have you provided the instantiated `const restaurantStore = new RestaurantStore()` ?

Comment: Yes I did. I have set other store like rootStore. This store is import every each stores and new these.